# Interrupt a trigger execution without a box message (tsql)

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I am writing a trigger for controlling a column. The script works as I want but my problem is in the raiseerror. I want the trigger to work without showing the error message to the user.

Can anyone who knows what is the equivalent of raiseerror without showing the error message to the user?

I tried with rollback transaction which gve me another error message instead, and I tried with return which did not interrupt the execution of the trigger.

This is my trigger:

```
DECLARE @val varchar(9)
SELECT @val= [DC_Piece] 
from INSERTED 
where INSERTED [DC_Domaine]=0 and INSERTED.[DC_IdCol]=6

IF UPDATE([DC_Piece])
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS( select [DO_PIECE] 
from DOCEN 
where  @val= [DO_Piece] and [DO_Domaine]=0 and [DO_Type]=6)
    RAISERROR('STOP',11,1)
END
```

Please help me

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @val= [DC_Piece] from INSERTED` - it's non-deterministic - you'll get *one arbitrary* row, and you'll be **ignoring** all others! You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: okay , can you give me an example pleaze

Answer (score 1):

You need to completely rewrite your trigger to take into account that it will be called **once per statement** (**NOT** per row!) and the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables can contain multiple rows which you should consider.

So try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_abort_insert
ON dbo.YourTableNameHere
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    -- check if any of the DC_Piece columns have been updated
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM Inserted i  
               INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.PrimaryKey = d.PrimaryKey  -- link the two pseudo tables on primary key
               WHERE i.DC_Piece <> d.DC_Piece   -- DC_Piece has changed
                 AND i.DC_Domaine = 0
                 AND i.DC_IdCol = 6)
        -- if your conditions are met --> just roll back the transaction
        -- nothing will be stored, no message is shown to the user 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION                 
END
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but I got this error message now that shows : the transaction ended in the trigger , the batch has been aboted